# How to find Oracle SYSTEMDB Tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an existing database and sql queries.

The query below works and returns rows.

```
Select * from systemdb.TABLE_A;
```

However when I tried to find the "**TABLE_A**" table using "Oracle SQL Developer", I cannot find it in the Tables or Views tree list.

Would like to ask where can I possibly find this table?

What is the meaning of "**systemdb**" keyword in the query above?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that query SYSTEMDB is the name of a *schema* in the database. A *schema* is almost synonymous with a *user*.

In SQL Developer you are presumably logged in as a different user than SYSTEMDB. To see the tables belonging to SYSTEMDB you expand "Other Users" at the bottom of the tree, then you find SYSTEMDB and expand that one, and then you can find "Tables" or "Views" of the user SYSTEMDB.

Comment: Hi thanks I'm able to find the table from "Other Users" named "SYSTEMDB", where I can successfully query. But I have another question, why when I query using another User's table I'm getting error: "Select  * from systemdbtest.TABLE_B;"? The error is "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist"? Thanks

Comment: That means that your user has not been granted SELECT privileges on TABLE_B in schema systemdbtest. You will have to ask your DBA for those privileges if you need them.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a tablespace / user created by PeopleSoft PeopleTools. There is not much to be found on it, but I found it [here](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2432371?tstart=0):

> have to prepare 4 environmets with PeopleSoft... If there any documentation when you create SystemDB?